# Magento resource Collection override

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, overrides, model

I have been trying to override Magento resource collection class. I have found few solutions but it seems can't get it to work.
The class is located in:

```
App/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php
```

This is the code to register module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
    <config>  
        <modules>  
            <XYZ_Reports>
                <active>true</active>  
                <codepool>local</codepool>  
            </XYZ_Reports>
        </modules>  
    </config>
```

And XML config file to override collection:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <XYZ_Reports>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </XYZ_Reports>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <reports>
                <rewrite>
                    <resource_order_collection>
                        XYZ_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
                    </resource_order_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </reports>
        </models>
    </global>    
</config>
```

This is a one version of config file. I have used different approaches including this one suggested by  [Damir Korpar - Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <XYZ_Reports>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </XYZ_Reports>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <reports_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_collection>
                        XYZ_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
                    </order_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </reports_resource>
        </models>
    </global>    
</config>
```

The new file located in:

```
app/local/XYZ/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php
```

And finally extended class:

```
<?php

class XYZ_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
{

    public function joinCustomerName($alias = 'name')
    {
        die('Overridden class'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem if someone have similar issue. I have typo in defining module. `<codepool>` should be camel-case. `<codePool>`.

Answer (score 4):

change your config.xml to

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <XYZ_Reports>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </XYZ_Reports>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <reports_resource>
                    <rewrite>
                        <order_collection>XYZ_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection</order_collection>
                    </rewrite>
                </reports_resource>
            </models>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Comment: As far as I know, XML parser discard the whitespace. But I have changed the code as you suggested and still can't get it to work.

Comment: in Magento this whitespace like above can cause issues. please make sure the model is succesfully overriden, create script in your magento root as following: `include "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();
echo get_class(Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection'));
exit;`

Comment: Still echo outs: `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection`

Comment: please check edited answer, i have tried it on my machine and it worked. whitespaces not allowed in magento. you can check it in your test script. if it helped you please accept the answer good luck

Comment: thanks @Anonymous. I have found the problem. I have a typo in defining module. `<codepool>` and I should have used `<codePool>`

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite class `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` in your custom module, you can try below code 
Code in your config.xml

```
....
        <global>
            <models>
                <yourmodule>
                    <class>Namespace_Yourmodule_Model</class>
                </yourmodule>

                <reports_resource>
                    <rewrite>                    
            <order_collection>Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_Reports_Resource_Order_Collection</order_collection>
                    </rewrite>
                </reports_resource>
            </models>
        </global>
    ....
```

Your rewrite class

```
<?php
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_Reports_Resource_Order_Collection extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection {
/*Your custom code/Methods */
}
```

Comment: I have seen this suggested in few places but I can't figured out what I should put for the model class name in `Namespace_Yourmodule_Model`